# How can I send an array of data to Google Tag Manager as seperate items?

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, google-tag-manager

I have an array of ten answers to a questionnaire:

```
var answers = ['answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3', ... ,'answer10']
```

The following sends the tags to Google Tag Manager as a single comma seperated string:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'questionnaireAnswers' : answers,
  'event' : 'questionnaire'
});
```

And this sends the items seperately but it doesn't seem to send all items (I assume it's causing a bottleneck during the for loop?):

```
for(var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) { 
  dataLayer.push({
    'questionnaireAnswers' : answers[i],
    'event' : 'questionnaire'
  });
}
```

I want to send these to Google Tag Manager at the same time but individually  as opposed to a comma seperated string, how would I achieve this?

Comment: 1. why do you ever want to send the answers to GA?  2. And if at all, how do you want to send them ?  as custom dimensions or events ?

Comment: The (multiple choice) answers need to be tracked across multiple user questionnaires to quantify the amount of people selecting each answer. Essentially the answers for each question are the same i.e. :

Very satisfied / satisfied / neutral / dissatisfied / very dissatisfied

We then want to have a Google Tag Manager event tracking Tag for "questionnaire answers" that lists the  answers and the number of times each answer has been selected across multiple users.

Comment: Mate that is more of a backend procedure you need to do. I dont recommed to use GA for that

Comment: @Tushar, we are collecting this information on the website backend (in the database) but we need to push it to GTM as we are collecting a lot more data there too and want to aggregate it to allow for detailed reporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) { 
  dataLayer.push({
    'questionnaireAnswers' : answers[i],
    'event' : 'questionnaire'
  });
}
```

This for loop will pass event *questionnaire* 10 (answer.length) times with one answer each time. You should try this instead:

1. Pass all answers at once:

   dataLayer.push({
     'questionnaireAnswers' : answers,
     'event' : 'questionnaire'
   });
2. And separate data in Tag Manager itself like this:
   a. Create a dataLayer variable called answers that stores complete array named, say, *answers*.
   b. Create 10 custom Javascript variables that access the dataLayer variable created in step a like this:

   function {
   return {{answers}}[i]} //i be the answer number

Comment: Hi @kushal, that sounds like a good plan - can you expand on the custom Javascript variables explanation? How do we then use these individual Javascript variables to populate our custom event in the Tag Manager dashboard without displaying the original array as a string?

Comment: Hi Adam, any variable in Tag Manager can be accessed by double curly brackets. ( eg. {{variable}} ).  So, create a trigger with the custom event - "questionnaire" and attach the tag that you want to fire with that trigger. All the 10 custom javascript variables will automatically be populated as soon as dataLayer.push() occurs. Hence, these variables will be available to you to fire the tags defined above.